# Fuzzy Matching on Date-Type values

Tags: algorithm, fuzzy, fuzzy-comparison

I don't have a real question but I'm more like seeking for creative input for a problem.

I want to compare two (most likely unequal) Date values and calculate the ratio of their similarity. So for example if I'd compare `08.01.2013` and `10.01.2013` I would get a relative high value but between `08.01.2013` and `17.04.1998`it would be really low.

But now I'm not sure how I should exactly calculate the similarity. First I was thinking about turning the Date values into Strings and then use the EditDistance on them (number of single char operations to transform one String into another). This seems like a good idea for some cases and I'll definitly implement it but I also need an appropriate calculation for something like `31.01.2013` and `02.02.2013`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the difference in days between two dates as a starting point? 
It is "low" for similar dates and "high" for unequal dates, then use arithmetic to obtain a "similarity ratio" which matches your requirements.

Consider a fixed reference date "early enough" in the past if you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks that helped me quite a bit. I took the time difference between the dates and then took the ratio between the time difference and a value that is considered as timespan that is expected/accepted for derivation.

Answer (score 0):

The edit distance can be calculated using the [Levenshtein](http://software-and-algorithms.blogspot.de/2012/09/damerau-levenshtein-edit-distance.html) distance.

A change in the year would mean a lot more "distance" than a change in the day.
The usual way to compare days would be to calculate the distance in days or hours. To do that, you'd convert both dates in a serial day number. Microsoft offers a [DateDiff()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/calculate-the-difference-between-two-date-or-time-values-HP001098486.aspx?CTT=3) function for date comparisons and distance calculations.